# How do I find sum of prime number integers in C based on an unlimited input?

Tags: c, loops, numbers

This is my prime number sum code. The input is unlimited but has to finish with 0. For example, the input 11, 4, 9, 17 should output the sum of prime numbers which in this case is 28. My code prints just 11. The loop stops once it has reached any derivative of 2 and I can not find a solution to this easy problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {
  int n, i, flag;
  int sumOfPrimeNumbers;
    sumOfPrimeNumbers = 0;
    flag = 0;
    do {
        for(i=2;i < n;i++)
        {
          scanf("%d", &n);
          if(n%i==0) {
            flag=1;
          }
        }
        if(flag==0) {
          sumOfPrimeNumbers = sumOfPrimeNumbers + n;
          break;
        }
    } while (n != 0);
  printf("%d\n", sumOfPrimeNumbers);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have not read the input n anywhere before the do-while loop?

Comment: Put the `flag=0;` line after the `do {`, and also the previous commentor is right, n is uninitilizaed when you hit the for loop.  The scanf should be after flag=0; and before the for loop.

Comment: You're using `n` before it has a valid value.

Comment: First: Do you know why your program *doesn't* work the way you want?

Comment: Thank you, pretty silly mistakes! Managed to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the commentors are right. You are using 'n' variable before accepting value from user and storing it in 'n' variable.